# Keeping a vector layer always on top

Tags: qgis, vector, qgis-plugins, c++, layers

I want to know how to keep a layer always on top of other layers! 
 After adding a vector layer ( QgisInterface->addVectorLayer ), I want that layer to always be displayed on top of layers added later. Can anybody help me with this ?

Answer (score 1):

try addMapLayer

```
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer( path, name, "ogr" )
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```