# QGIS and python: Keep a layer always on top of the others

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins, layers

I am working on a python plugin for QGIS using a layer containing linestrings, which I would like to have on top at all times. I have added the layer like the following:

```
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer, addToLegend=False)
```

I don't want the layer to appear in the *Layers Panel*.

A [similar question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23990/keeping-a-vector-layer-always-on-top) has been asked here without an accepted and for me meaningful answer.

According to [Nathan W](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119280/setting-layer-visibility-in-qgis-python-api) I can use the `canvas` method [`setLayerSet`](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapCanvas.html#ad4a81bc8f6249f49a70fd50406dd20f3) to set the render order on the canvas layers.

- In case the current project already contains several layers, I need to know the current rendering order to correctly place my layer on top without disturbing the current order.
- In case the user adds a new layer, how do I prevent the new layer from being ontop of mine? Is this handled by listening for some kind of a *layer reordered* signal on the canvas?

**Question:** What is the correct approach to handle this issue?

---

**Update with solution notes:**
I have implemented the answer provided by **[dmh126](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/172673/205)**. To follow up on my questions I have determined that, it looks like `canvas.layers()` provide the layers in the order last given to the `canvas.setLayerSet(...)`. Thus this list of layers can be used to include my layer on top directly:

```
layers = [my_layer] + canvas.layers()
canvas.setLayerSet([QgsMapCanvasLayer(x) for x in layers if x.id() != my_layer.id()])
# I don't want my layer in the list twice if it was already there due to a previous update.
```

The `canvas` signal `layersChanged` can be used to determine a change in the layers (new layer, removed layer, visibility change...), but remember to disconnect the listener when calling `canvas.setLayerSet(...)' because it will fire the signal again, probably causing a never ending call to the method called by the listener:

```
QObject.disconnect(canvas, SIGNAL('layersChanged()'), my_method)
layers = [my_layer] + canvas.layers()
canvas.setLayerSet([QgsMapCanvasLayer(x) for x in layers if x.id() != my_layer.id()])
QObject.connect(canvas, SIGNAL('layersChanged()'), my_method)
```

If I need to hide my layer, I can just remove it from the layer set like above:

```
layers = canvas.layers()
canvas.setLayerSet([QgsMapCanvasLayer(x) for x in layers if x.id() != my_layer.id()])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this:

1. Create a function, that will set your layer on top (I guess there are a few solutions, you can use `canvas.setLayerSet([top_layer, bottom_layer1, ...])` or something).
2. Choose a signal from the list: http://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapCanvas.html
   It can be `layersChanged()` or something that occurs after you add a new layer or change hierarchy.
3. Connect your function to that canvas signal.

Comment: How do I get the other layers so I can create the correct layer order with my layer on top? This is the issue I can't seem to get my head around.

Comment: `canvas.layers()` gives you a list of layers from the registry, now you can iterate over that list and set a proper order in new list for example.